# Having trouble porting this from vb.net to Java AES encryption

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, encryption, aes

Here is the full working example of something encoded in .net and decoded in Java and vice-versa

```
    Private Function Decrypt(cipherText As String) As String
dim _encryptionkey as string = "kmjfds(#1231SDSA()#rt32geswfkjFJDSKFJDSFd"
        Dim cipherBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)
        Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
            Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(_EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, _
             &H76})
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length)
                    cs.Close()
                End Using
                cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray())
            End Using
        End Using
        Return cipherText
    End Function
```

Here is the Java equivalent.  Thanks for everyone's help!  Make sure to install the JCE policy in the security folder of your Java as well.

```
String myData = "kgxCSfBSw5BRxmjgc4qYhwN12dxG0dyf=";
        byte[] salt = new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
        String pw  = "kmjfds(#1231SDSA()#rt32geswfkjFJDSKFJDSFd";

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pw.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 384);
        Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        byte[] key = new byte[32];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 32);
        System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 32, iv, 0, 16);


        SecretKeySpec secretSpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretSpec,ivSpec);
            cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretSpec,ivSpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //byte[] decordedValue;
        //decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(myData);
        //decordedValue = myData.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
          //byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(myData.getBytes());
        //Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(myData.getBytes()));
            //String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        byte[] decodedValue  = new Base64().decode(myData.getBytes());



          String clearText = "ljfva09876FK";


          //String encodedValue  = new Base64().encodeAsString(clearText.getBytes("UTF-16"));



          byte[] cipherBytes = cipher1.doFinal(clearText.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
          //String cipherText = new String(cipherBytes, "UTF8");
          String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherBytes);
          System.out.println(encoded);


            byte[] decValue =    cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);

            System.out.println(new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```

Comment: I tried to accept your answer and it said I did not have enough reputation points.  I am new to this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iteration count should be 1000 (instead of 1), which is the recommended minimum in the RFC and the (unspecified) default of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

> For the methods in this document, a minimum
>      of 1000 iterations is recommended

So that would translate into:

```
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pw.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 384);
```

within the Java code. Note that a higher iteration count is highly recommended, especially if weaker passwords are allowed. 40K-100K is about the minimum now.

---

The incorrectly named `Unicode` actually means UTF-16 in .NET, so you should use:

```
new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE)
```

within the last `println` statement of the Java code.

Comment: both are using 1 itteration, so it should not cause an issue on the example posted.

Comment: How are you decoding properly, and mine is giving me an error.  Please see revised code I just updated.

Comment: @VinnieSenese Great, thanks for the accept. We can remove all of the comments now, as they are not needed anymore. I'll delete all except this one for now. PS you should be able to upvote now, you've got enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer thanks to Maarten Bodewes

```
String myData = "kgxCSfBSw5BRxmjgc4qYhwN12dxG0=";
    byte[] salt = new byte[] {0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76};
    String pw  = "kmjfds(#1231SDSA()#rt32geswfkjFJDSKFJDSFd";

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pw.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 384);
    Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] key = new byte[32];
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 32);
    System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 32, iv, 0, 16);


    SecretKeySpec secretSpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretSpec,ivSpec);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //byte[] decordedValue;
    //decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(myData);
    //decordedValue = myData.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
      //byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(myData.getBytes());
    //Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(myData.getBytes()));
        //String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    byte[] decodedValue  = new Base64().decode(myData.getBytes());


    byte[] decValue =    cipher.doFinal(decodedValue);

        System.out.println(new String(decValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
```